# Need help creating this aggregate SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

[image: aggregated calculations on several fields]

Is it possible to create a SQL query that will return this result set?

Thanks for any suggestions or feedback.

Comment: thanks Dale, will attempt to use formatted text next time, I wonder if there's an easy way to convert an Excel table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join and do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    b.id,
    b.name
    max(case when tib.content = 'math book'  then 'Yes' else 'No' end) has_math,
    max(case when tib.content = 'SQL book'   then 'Yes' else 'No' end) has_sql,
    max(case when tib.content = 'comic book' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) has_comic
from bag b
inner join things_in_bag tib on tib.bag_id = b.id
group by b.id, b.name
```

Comment: Wrong database ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yep... fixed already.

Comment: thanks! this is exactly what I was trying to figure out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select bag_id,
       max(case when content = 'math book' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as has_math_book,
       max(case when content = 'SQL book' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as has_sql_book,
       max(case when content = 'comic book' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as has_comic_book
from things_in_bag
group by bag_id;
```